# Accessing each TILE in an NTILE operation and setting dfferent column values to each group in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want the result as per my image from a table in SQL Server 2008.

I assume, the best way to do is group based on Column B and Column C using NTILES to split the rows into TILE groups.

In that how can I set same values for the Column D within a group

- Group A -same column value in Column D
- Group B -same column value in
  Column D (but it is different than Group A column D value)

So how can I access each group to set these values *without a cursor*?[image]

PS:Rvalue1,Rvalue2,Rvalue3 ,RvalueX has no relation to each other,it is just random unique identifier(GUID for each group)
[edited as per comments from @Martin Smith]

Comment: So for each unique `ColB, ColC` pairing you are assigning `Col D` a specific  value? Is it arbitrary which group is `1,2,3` or is there some logic to this that I can't discern? Doesn't seem to be ordered by either  `ColB` or `ColC`

Comment: Group based on ColB and Col C

Comment: I consider AD in One group and CE in another group and B in another group. Is there any mistake in the way I explained it?If so, then by groups I meant it to be in this way as(AD,CE,B)

Comment: Oh Sorry @MartinSmith yes, It is similar to what you said,my aim is to assign D with specific values for each unique Col B and Col C.

Comment: Still haven't answered my question! What if the result was that `A,D -> RVALUE3`,  `C,E -> RVALUE1` and `B -> RVALUE2` would that be equally correct? If not why not?

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct. It is just a uniquenumber GUID.It has no relation to eachother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I followed:

Store the distinct ColB ColC values in a tableVariable having an Identity Column

Iterate through the tableVariable using a while loop and update the parent table ColD value based on the Values of ColB and ColC 
Where
ColB and ColC values will be the value in each row of the condensed/grouped tableVariable.

The Identity column is used to iterate through the tableVariable row by row.